# Make a Negated General Impedance Converter

Tags: analog, impedance, transfer-function

A General Impedance Converter (GIC) looks like this:

[image]
Source: [http://www.ee.nmt.edu/~wedeward/EE212L/SP15/ImpedanceConverters.html](http://www.ee.nmt.edu/%7Ewedeward/EE212L/SP15/ImpedanceConverters.html)

Where

$$Z_{tot} = \frac{Z_1*Z_3*Z_5}{Z_2*Z_4}$$

But I need a circuit that gives me \$ \frac{1}{Z_{tot}}\$

How would I create a circuit that gives me \$ \frac{1}{Z_{tot}}\$ for Zin?

(Or something like \$ Z_{in} = \frac{Z_2*Z_4}{Z_1*Z_3*Z_5}\$)

The problem is if I put an inductor on this circuit, I can't select a series of impedance's Z_1 through Z_5 using only resistors and capacitors to end up with a combined impedance of 1.

Comment: Hmm interesting.

Comment: So you want a general conductance converter (GCC?)

Comment: @VoltageSpike So you just need to insert a transconductance -- something that presents current at the output given voltage at the input. Like a BJT. ;)

Comment: @LvW I want to be able to reverse the impedance of an inductor, using only resistors and capacitors. So if I had an inductor on Zin, I could match the impedance with an inverse impedance.

Comment: ....and what is the unit for the "inverse impedance"? Is it capacitor?

Comment: @jonk The IEEE says that the inverse of conductance is **admittance**, with the unit of siemens. The commonly used quantity symbol (such as a variable in an equation) is *Y*.

Comment: @LvW The inverse of capacitance is **elastance**, with units of \$F^{-1}\$. The commonly used quantity symbol is *S*.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Yup. I was being sloppy.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson - my question (inverese impedance) was an ironic one....I do not understand at all the problem. When a circuit has a certain input impedance, at the same time it has an admittance which is the inverse of this impedance. So - what is the OP looking for?

Comment: If I read the last line of the problem description right, he is looking for an impedance that has the unit 1/impedance (1/Ohm). An answer deserves 50 points.

Comment: If I put any impedance at the source, I want exactly the opposite impedance presented by the circuit

Comment: Are you trying to make an automated parallel tuned circuit? Are we talking about signals and not powers here?

Comment: 1) No 2) I want to invert the impedance of an inductor to end up with no phase from the inductor, for the voltage.

Comment: @LvW There is no problem. You asked a straightforward question. I thought an answer was in order, if not for you then for the next reader. If you intended irony maybe you should have added a smiley face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, the <s>inverse of the inverse</s>converse of the converse is the original impedance which was a filter with a bunch of RC's.

NIC Negative Impedance Converters **give the negative of impedance** , not the inversion.

[image]

The performance as shown would be highly vulnerable with stray coupling.  Yet the desired or expected performance was never specified.

Comment: So, if I put an inductor on Vin can I get 1/Z_l from the circuit?

Comment: You have it backwards.. on the top half you put C on Vin+ then Vin appears as an inductor yet current limited...

Comment: The input resistance at the node Vin is Z=-Z1Z3Z5/Z2Z4. Hence, there is only a sign inversion. Is that the solution the OP was asking for?

Comment: Yes @LvW Thankyou.  The conversion is just the opposite polarity not an inversion. my bad choice of words.

Comment: I rather think that the OP has made a bad choice of words resp. symbols. He did mention Zin=1/Ztot.....whatever this could mean...